# How can a list of numerical identifiers be added to a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello and welcome to my question.

I want to create a list of **unique, numerical, position-based identifiers** to denote the position of items in a column of values in a dataframe.

Here's an example of what I want (in column `Position`):

```
tibble(Fruit = c(rep("Apple", 3), rep("Pear", 2), rep("Orange", 4)),
       Variety = c("Gala", "Envy", "Pink Lady", "Anjou", "Bartlett", "Blood", "Seville", "Mandarin", "Bergamot"),
       Position = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4))
```

As you can see, the whole number value of the identifier denotes `Fruit`, while the decimal value denotes the `Variety`.

**I'd like a method to create these unique position identifiers** for use in another project (using ganttrify, an excellent but particular function). Bonus points for a dplyr-friendly solution.

Comment: Your data does not capture the whole idea. What happens if you have repeated values in Variety? or even repeated rows? edit taking that into consideration

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @onyamu, but this is just an example of the kind of dataset in which I'll be using this solution. There will not be repeating instances of the "Variety" analogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` to create the first index based on 'Fruit' and `rowid` (from `data.table`) to get the second sequence index and paste them in `sprintf`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Position2 = sprintf('%d.%d', match(Fruit, unique(Fruit)), rowid(Fruit)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  Fruit  Variety   Position Position2
  <chr>  <chr>        <dbl> <chr>    
1 Apple  Gala           1.1 1.1      
2 Apple  Envy           1.2 1.2      
3 Apple  Pink Lady      1.3 1.3      
4 Pear   Anjou          2.1 2.1      
5 Pear   Bartlett       2.2 2.2      
6 Orange Blood          3.1 3.1      
7 Orange Seville        3.2 3.2      
8 Orange Mandarin       3.3 3.3      
9 Orange Bergamot       3.4 3.4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is `dplyr` way using `group_indices`. The trick is to overcome the alphabetical ordering of `group_indices` with the code below:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = group_indices(., factor(Fruit, levels = unique(Fruit)))) %>% 
  group_by(Fruit) %>% 
  mutate(Position2 = paste(id, row_number(), sep = "."), .keep="unused") %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
Fruit  Variety   Position Position2
  <chr>  <chr>        <dbl> <chr>    
1 Apple  Gala           1.1 1.1      
2 Apple  Envy           1.2 1.2      
3 Apple  Pink Lady      1.3 1.3      
4 Pear   Anjou          2.1 2.1      
5 Pear   Bartlett       2.2 2.2      
6 Orange Blood          3.1 3.1      
7 Orange Seville        3.2 3.2      
8 Orange Mandarin       3.3 3.3      
9 Orange Bergamot       3.4 3.4
```

Comment: I notice this script does not work with the newer pipeline operator, ```|>```. An idea why?

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `paste0` + `match` + `ave`

```
> transform(df, position2 = paste0(match(Fruit,unique(Fruit)), ".", ave(Variety, Fruit, FUN = seq_along)))
   Fruit   Variety Position position2
1  Apple      Gala      1.1       1.1
2  Apple      Envy      1.2       1.2
3  Apple Pink Lady      1.3       1.3
4   Pear     Anjou      2.1       2.1
5   Pear  Bartlett      2.2       2.2
6 Orange     Blood      3.1       3.1
7 Orange   Seville      3.2       3.2
8 Orange  Mandarin      3.3       3.3
9 Orange  Bergamot      3.4       3.4
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at rank. Look at the ties.method argument. You may want to use ties.method="first".